# Android CameraX | Color detection

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera, android-camerax, color-detection

I'm working with the new CameraX on Android.

I did a basic application (similar to the "Get Started") in which I have a camera preview and a luminosity analyzer. Every second I display my lumonisity in a TextView.

Now, following the CameraX guidelines, I would like to do color detection. Every second or so, I want to have the color from the pixel in the center of my screen.

The fact is that I don't know how to do color detection following the same sructure as luminosity analyzer.

**Luminosity Analyzer Class :**

```
class LuminosityAnalyzer : ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {

private var lastTimeStamp = 0L
private val TAG = this.javaClass.simpleName
var luma = BehaviorSubject.create<Double>()

override fun analyze(image: ImageProxy, rotationDegrees: Int) {
    val currentTimeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val intervalInSeconds = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1)
    val deltaTime = currentTimeStamp - lastTimeStamp
    if(deltaTime >= intervalInSeconds) {
        val buffer = image.planes[0].buffer
        val data = buffer.toByteArray()
        val pixels = data.map { it.toInt() and 0xFF }
        luma.onNext(pixels.average())
        lastTimeStamp = currentTimeStamp
        Log.d(TAG, "Average luminosity: ${luma.value}")
    }


private fun ByteBuffer.toByteArray(): ByteArray {
    rewind()
    val data = ByteArray(remaining())
    get(data)
    return data
}
}
```

**Main Activity :**

```
/* display the luminosity */
private fun createLuminosityAnalyzer(): ImageAnalysis{
    val analyzerConfig = ImageAnalysisConfig.Builder().apply {
        setLensFacing(lensFacing)
        setImageReaderMode(ImageAnalysis.ImageReaderMode.ACQUIRE_LATEST_IMAGE)
    }.build()

    val analyzer = ImageAnalysis(analyzerConfig).apply {
        val luminosityAnalyzer = LuminosityAnalyzer()
        luminosityAnalyzer.luma
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({
            // success
            luminosity.text = it.toString()
        },{
            // error
            Log.d(TAG, "Can not get luminosity :(")
        })
        setAnalyzer(executor, luminosityAnalyzer)
    }
    return analyzer
}
```

**How can I do something equivalent but being a Color Analyzer ?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I figured out how to do it by myself

**Color Analyzer Class :**

```
class ColorAnalyzer : ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {

private var lastTimeStamp = 0L
private val TAG = this.javaClass.simpleName
var hexColor = BehaviorSubject.create<Any>()

/* every 100ms, analyze the image we receive from camera */
override fun analyze(image: ImageProxy, rotationDegrees: Int) {
    val currentTimeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val intervalInMilliSeconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMillis(100)
    val deltaTime = currentTimeStamp - lastTimeStamp
    if(deltaTime >= intervalInMilliSeconds) {

        val imageBitmap = image.image?.toBitmap()
        val pixel = imageBitmap!!.getPixel((imageBitmap.width/2), (imageBitmap.height/2))
        val red = Color.red(pixel)
        val blue = Color.blue(pixel)
        val green = Color.green(pixel)
        hexColor.onNext(String.format("#%02x%02x%02x", red, green, blue))
        Log.d(TAG, "Color: ${hexColor.value}")

        lastTimeStamp = currentTimeStamp
    }
}

// convert the image into a bitmap
private fun Image.toBitmap(): Bitmap {
    val yBuffer = planes[0].buffer // Y
    val uBuffer = planes[1].buffer // U
    val vBuffer = planes[2].buffer // V

    val ySize = yBuffer.remaining()
    val uSize = uBuffer.remaining()
    val vSize = vBuffer.remaining()

    val nv21 = ByteArray(ySize + uSize + vSize)

    yBuffer.get(nv21, 0, ySize)
    vBuffer.get(nv21, ySize, vSize)
    uBuffer.get(nv21, ySize + vSize, uSize)

    val yuvImage = YuvImage(nv21, ImageFormat.NV21, this.width, this.height, null)
    val out = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    yuvImage.compressToJpeg(Rect(0, 0, yuvImage.width, yuvImage.height), 50, out)
    val imageBytes = out.toByteArray()
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.size)
}
}
```

**Main Activity :**

```
 /* Get the color from Color Analyzer Class */
private fun createColorAnalyzer(): ImageAnalysis{
    val analyzerConfig = ImageAnalysisConfig.Builder().apply {
        setLensFacing(lensFacing)
        setImageReaderMode(ImageAnalysis.ImageReaderMode.ACQUIRE_LATEST_IMAGE)
    }.build()

    val analyzer = ImageAnalysis(analyzerConfig).apply {
        val colorAnalyzer = ColorAnalyzer()
        colorAnalyzer.hexColor
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({
                // success
                colorName.text = it.toString() //hexa code in the textView
                colorName.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(it.toString())) //background color of the textView
                (sight.drawable as GradientDrawable).setStroke(10, Color.parseColor(it.toString())) //border color of the sight in the middle of the screen
            },{
                // error
                Log.d(TAG, "Can not get color :(")
            })
        setAnalyzer(executor, colorAnalyzer)
    }
    return analyzer
}
```

Hope it will be useful for someone ;)

**EDIT :**

If you read the @Minhaz answer getting the color by doing *image -> bitmap -> getPixel()* is not very efficient. The most effective is to do *image -> RGB*.

So here's the Minhaz answer working with Kotlin.

**Color Analyzer Class :**

```
class ColorAnalyzer : ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {

private var lastAnalyzedTimestamp = 0L


private fun ByteBuffer.toByteArray(): ByteArray {
    rewind()    // Rewind the buffer to zero
    val data = ByteArray(remaining())
    get(data)   // Copy the buffer into a byte array
    return data // Return the byte array
}


private fun getRGBfromYUV(image: ImageProxy): Triple<Double, Double, Double> {
    val planes = image.planes

    val height = image.height
    val width = image.width

    // Y
    val yArr = planes[0].buffer
    val yArrByteArray = yArr.toByteArray()
    val yPixelStride = planes[0].pixelStride
    val yRowStride = planes[0].rowStride

    // U
    val uArr = planes[1].buffer
    val uArrByteArray =uArr.toByteArray()
    val uPixelStride = planes[1].pixelStride
    val uRowStride = planes[1].rowStride

    // V
    val vArr = planes[2].buffer
    val vArrByteArray = vArr.toByteArray()
    val vPixelStride = planes[2].pixelStride
    val vRowStride = planes[2].rowStride

    val y = yArrByteArray[(height * yRowStride + width * yPixelStride) / 2].toInt() and 255
    val u = (uArrByteArray[(height * uRowStride + width * uPixelStride) / 4].toInt() and 255) - 128
    val v = (vArrByteArray[(height * vRowStride + width * vPixelStride) / 4].toInt() and 255) - 128

    val r = y + (1.370705 * v)
    val g = y - (0.698001 * v) - (0.337633 * u)
    val b = y + (1.732446 * u)

    return Triple(r,g,b)
}


// analyze the color
override fun analyze(image: ImageProxy, rotationDegrees: Int) {
    val currentTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis()
    if (currentTimestamp - lastAnalyzedTimestamp >= TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMillis(100)) {

        val colors = getRGBfromYUV(image)
        var hexColor = String.format("#%02x%02x%02x", colors.first.toInt(), colors.second.toInt(), colors.third.toInt())
        Log.d("test", "hexColor: $hexColor")

        lastAnalyzedTimestamp = currentTimestamp
    }

}
}
```

Comment: It's very inefficient if you convert each YUV frame to Bitmap and then get the color of a pixel or two from it. The YUV data itself has three planes one with Y buffer (luminosity) and two other buffers indicating chroma values U and V buffer. While there is one Y byte for each pixel the U & V are available as interleaved values. Using the YUV data itself and the Pixel Stride and Row Stride one can get color value of any pixel, rather than converting whole image to Bitmap (which btw is ~ 8 / 3 times bigger than the YUV in memory)

Comment: If you are looking for code sample for an efficient solution, let me know - I shall try to come up with one over here.

Comment: Your solution is very welcome. On the other hand I will have a total of 16 zones of pixels to analyze the color from, so converting the whole image to bitmap becomes less inefficient I suppose

Comment: Hey it's me again, I really need that efficient solution that you were talking about. I'm trying to do it but I'm struggling to get the color directly from YUV planes. Thank you ! @Minhaz

Comment: Added the logic as comment.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the comment, if your target is to only get center pixel color the logic of converting the whole YUV image to Bitmap and then analysing the center value may be very inefficient. You can directly look into the color in YUV image by targeting the right pixel. In a YUV image you have three planes one for Y (1 byte per pixel) and U & V plane (.5 byte per pixel, interleaved). Ignoring the rotation at the moment as center pixel should be same regardless of rotation (discarding possibility of odd value of height or width). The efficient logic for getting center pixel rgb values would look like:

```
planes = imageProxy.getPlanes()

val height = imageProxy.getHeight()
val width = imageProxy.getWidth()

// You may have to find the logic to get array from ByteBuffer
// Y
val yArr = planes[0].buffer.array()
val yPixelStride = planes[0].getPixelStride()
val yRowStride = planes[0].getRowStride()

// U
val uArr = planes[1].buffer.array()
val uPixelStride = planes[1].getPixelStride()
val uRowStride = planes[1].getRowStride()

// V
val vArr = planes[2].buffer.array()
val vPixelStride = planes[2].getPixelStride()
val vRowStride = planes[2].getRowStride()

val y = yArr[(height * yRowStride + width * yPixelStride) / 2] & 255 
val u = (uArr[(height * uRowStride + width * uPixelStride) / 4] & 255) - 128
val v = (vArr[(height * vRowStride + width * vPixelStride) / 4] & 255) - 128 

val r = y + (1.370705 * v);
val g = y - (0.698001 * v) - (0.337633 * u);
val b = y + (1.732446 * u);
```

Reference to magic values: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV#Y%E2%80%B2UV420sp_(NV21)_to_RGB_conversion_(Android)

Try using this logic in your Kotlin code to see if it's working and is fast for realtime operations. This should definitely reduce a `O(height * width)` operation to constant time complexity.